# Как исключить возможность клика по нескольким вью одновременно?

Tags: android, view

В `LinearLayout` вложены несколько `view`, каждый из которых при клике на него выполняет какое-то действие(к примеру, вызывает диалоговое окно). Чисто теоретически пользователь может кликнуть по енскольким вью одновременно, тогда появится несколько диалоговых окон, что крайне нежелательно. Как это предотвратить?

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971484/how-to-avoid-multiple-button-click-at-same-time-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Нашла ответ на свой вопрос.

Существует несколько вариантов решения этой проблемы.

**1 Вариант**  - задать свойство `android:splitMotionEvents="false"` в макете активности.

Если все кликабельные `view` находятся в одном родительском контейнере, тогда  у родителя прописывается  `android:splitMotionEvents="false"`

Если кликабельные `view` располагаются в разных контейнерах, вложенных в один общий, либо как-то иначе (в разной степени вложенности), тогда у всех контейнеров нужно прописать `android:splitMotionEvents="false"`

**2 Вариант** - использовать Ontouch вместо Onclick:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // если палец опускается на дисплей
                setViewClickableFalse();// метод, который делает все view некликабельными
                // появляется диалоговое окно
                break;
        }
        return false;
    } 
protected void setViewClickableFalse(){

        for (View view:views){ //views - массив, содержащий все кликабельные view
            view.setClickable(false);
        }
    }
```

Но этот вариант, не подойдет, к примеру, если используется scrollview, т.к. при попытке скроллинга будет вылетать диалоговое окно.

**3 вариант**- отключить мультитач во всем приложении, но мне это не подходит.